# No LEFT function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to big query and not sure on the solution to extract the first part of the U.K. postcode. As the left function does not seem to be supported.
So my postcode is
W2 1su
Se1 5bt
Se23 7an

I would like to extract
w2
Se1
Se22

Any ideas how I can do this in big query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
             case when CHAR_LENGTH(DBS_Formatted_Postcode)=6 then substr(DBS_Formatted_Postcode,1,2)
              when CHAR_LENGTH(DBS_Formatted_Postcode)=7 then substr(DBS_Formatted_Postcode,1,3)
              when CHAR_LENGTH(DBS_Formatted_Postcode)=8 then substr(DBS_Formatted_Postcode,1,4)
              end as postcode_district,
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use `SPLIT(DBS_Formatted_Postcode, ' ')[OFFSET(0)]` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SPLIT(DBS_Formatted_Postcode, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS postcode_district
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

```
Row postcode_district    
1   W2   
2   Se1  
3   Se23
```

Note: in reality - there are quite a number of ways to do so in BQ - for example another option is to use regular expression function like `REGEXP_EXTRACT(DBS_Formatted_Postcode, r'([^ ]+) ')`